# Ensure interface type of nested member

Tags: javascript, interface, typescript

I'm using JS/TypeScript and have the following situation:

```
enum ResultFlag {
    BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE = 1, ABOVE_MEASUREMENT_RANGE,
    BELOW_PATHOLOGICAL_RANGE, ABOVE_PATHOLOGICAL_RANGE
}

const FlagDefs = {
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: {
        icon: 'down', color: palette.grey200
    },
    [ResultFlag.ABOVE_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: {
        icon: 'up', color: palette.grey200
    },
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_PATHOLOGICAL_RANGE]: {
        letter: '<', color: palette.accent
    },
    [ResultFlag.ABOVE_PATHOLOGICAL_RANGE]: {
        letter: '>', color: palette.accent
    }
}
```

I'd like to ensure the following interface to the members of FlagDefs:

```
interface IFlagDef {
    icon?: string;
    letter?: string;
    color: string;
}
```

The following does not compile:

```
const FlagDefs = {
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: IFlagDef ({
        icon: 'down', color: palette.accent
    }) 
    //...
}
```

The following does compile but indeed is completely pointless, because the cast just enforces the interface without checking anything:

```
const FlagDefs = {
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: {
        icon: 'down', color: palette.accent
    } as IFlagDef
    //...
}
```

I finally came up with a working solution:

```
const FlagDefs = {
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: ((): IFlagDef => { return {
        icon: 'down', color: palette.accent
    }; })()
    // ...
}
```

I wonder if anybody knows a simpler and more direct way of making sure all members of FlagDefs properly implement the interface IFlagDef?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by adding explicit type declaration for `FlagDefs`:

```
type FDStorage = { [key: number]: IFlagDef; };

const FlagDefs: FDStorage = {
    [ResultFlag.BELOW_MEASUREMENT_RANGE]: {
        icon: 'down', color: palette.accent
    }
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, I used `number` as key type, since enum values are numbers, and only `number` or `string` types are allowed as key types.

Comment: Awesome it works! If you remove the () => {} closure hack, which is no longer needed, I'll mark it as the answer!

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally copy&pasted wrong code sample from your post :)